# Navigation :hover CSS not working in IE but does in JSFiddle

Tags: html, css

On a website I am building I have a navigation system that was partially constructed from code that isn't mine (which makes things easy in some ways, and frustrating in others).  It works great on all browsers and on all websites I've used it on before except this one, in Internet Explorer.  I am using IE10 and don't have easy means of testing in other versions.

The weird thing is, when I made a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/8B42F/) of the problematic code, it worked perfectly in Internet Explorer.  So to show you the problem I'm going to have to give you a link to the site, and hopefully someone will know why the :hover CSS event isn't triggering.
http://www.psychmedintl.org/

The code is compiled by PHP and therefor has a linear formatting, I apologize for that, but the code in the JSFiddle is that same output after I corrected the formatting.

Here is the CSS:

```
#menuitem
{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px transparent solid;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: regular;
    width: 96px;
    text-align: center;
    background: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}
#menuitem:hover
{
    background: transparent url("images/menu_hover.png") repeat-x;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#nav 
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    /*margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;*/
    height: 48px;
    width: auto;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -4px;
}
#nav li.top {display:inline-block; float:center;}
#nav li a.top_link 
{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px transparent solid;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: regular;
    width: 96px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}
#nav li a.top_link span {float:left; display:inline; padding:0 24px 0 12px; height:36px;}
#nav li a.top_link span.down {float:left; display:none; padding:0 24px 0 12px; height:36px; }
#nav li a.top_link:hover {color:#000;}
#nav li a.top_link:hover span {}
#nav li a.top_link:hover span.down {}

#nav li:hover > a.top_link {color:#000; background: url(images/menu_hover.png) repeat-x;}
#nav li:hover > a.top_link span {background:url(images/menu_hover.png) repeat-x right top;}
#nav li:hover > a.top_link span.down {background:url(images/menu_a_hover.png) repeat-x right top;}

/* Default list styling */

#nav li:hover {position:relative; z-index: 10;}

/* keep the 'next' level invisible by placing it off screen. */
#nav ul, 
#nav li:hover ul ul,
#nav li:hover ul li:hover ul ul,
#nav li:hover ul li:hover ul li:hover ul ul,
#nav li:hover ul li:hover ul li:hover ul li:hover ul ul
{
    position:absolute; left:-9999px; top:-9999px; width:0; height:0; margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;
}

#nav li:hover ul.sub
{
    min-width: 128px;
    left: 0;
    top: 40px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 3px;
    border:2px solid #95eded;
    white-space: nowrap;
    /*width: 240px; */
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
}
#nav li:hover ul.sub li
{
    display:block;
    height: 34px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    /* width:140px; */
    width: 100%;
    font-weight:normal;
}
#nav li:hover ul.sub li a
{
    display:block;
    font-size: 16px;
    height:34px;
    /*width:140px; */
    margin-right: 6px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height:25px;
    text-indent:5px;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    position: relative;
}
#nav li:hover ul.sub li:hover
{
    background:#95eded;
    color:#fff;
    position: relative;
}
#nav li:hover ul li:hover ul,
#nav li:hover ul li:hover ul li:hover ul,
#nav li:hover ul li:hover ul li:hover ul li:hover ul,
#nav li:hover ul li:hover ul li:hover ul li:hover ul li:hover ul
{
    min-width: 128px;
    left: 64px;
    top: 24px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 3px;
    border:2px solid #95eded;
    white-space: nowrap;
    white-space:nowrap; 
    width: auto;
    height:auto;
    position: absolute;
}
#nav #arrow
{
    margin-right: 8px;
    background-image: url('images/navarrow.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right; 
}
```

And here is the HTML.  Please ignore the preview pictures and corresponding JavaScript, they are irrelevant.

```
<div id="menu">
<ul id="nav">                   
    <!-- Home Page Tab -->
    <li class="top"><a href="?p=home" class="top_link">Home</a></li>
    <li class='top'><a href='javascript:void();' class='top_link'>Who We Are</a>
        <ul class='sub'>
            <li id='arrow' onmouseover="changePreview('boardofdirectors','0');" onmouseout="changePreview('blank','0');"><a href='javascript:void();'>Board of Directors</a>
                <ul>
                    <div style='width: 100px; display:inline-block'>
                        <li  nmouseover="changePreview('judy','33');" onmouseout="changePreview('blank','33');"><a href='?dp=10'>Judy</a></li>
                        <li  onmouseover="changePreview('stacy','33');" onmouseout="changePreview('blank','33');"><a href='?dp=1'>Stacy</a></li>
                        <li  onmouseover="changePreview('kira','33');" onmouseout="changePreview('blank','33');"><a href='?dp=5'>Kira</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <img id='previewImage33' style='display: inline-block;' src='images/previews/blank.jpg' width=102 height=102/>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id='arrow' onmouseover="changePreview('providers','0');" onmouseout="changePreview('blank','0');"><a href='javascript:void();'>Providers</a>
                <ul>
                    <div style='width: 100px; display:inline-block'>
                        <li  onmouseover="changePreview('stacy','37');" onmouseout="changePreview('blank','37');"><a href='?dp=1'>Stacy</a></li>
                        <li  onmouseover="changePreview('kira','37');" onmouseout="changePreview('blank','37');"><a href='?dp=5'>Kira</a></li>
                        <li  onmouseover="changePreview('libby','37');" onmouseout="changePreview('blank','37');"><a href='?dp=9'>Libby</a></li>
                        <li  onmouseover="changePreview('zeke','37');" onmouseout="changePreview('blank','37');"><a href='?dp=8'>Zeke</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <img id='previewImage37' style='display: inline-block;' src='images/previews/blank.jpg' width=136 height=136/>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id='arrow' onmouseover="changePreview('administration','0');" onmouseout="changePreview('blank','0');"><a href='javascript:void();'>Administration</a>
                <ul>
                    <div style='width: 100px; display:inline-block'>
                        <li  onmouseover="changePreview('sam','36');" onmouseout="changePreview('blank','36');"><a href='?dp=11'>Sam</a></li>
                        <li  onmouseover="changePreview('morgan','36');" onmouseout="changePreview('blank','36');"><a href='?dp=43'>Morgan</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <img id='previewImage36' style='display: inline-block;' src='images/previews/blank.jpg' width=68 height=68/>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='top'><a href='javascript:void();' class='top_link'>What We Do</a>
        <ul class='sub'>
            <li  onmouseover="changePreview('disasterrelief','0');" onmouseout="changePreview('blank','0');"><a href='?dp=6'>Disaster Relief</a></li>
            <li  onmouseover="changePreview('trainingandeducation','0');" onmouseout="changePreview('blank','0');"><a href='?dp=7'>Training and Education</a></li>
            <li  onmouseover="changePreview('medicalandclinicalwork','0');" onmouseout="changePreview('blank','0');"><a href='?dp=13'>Medical and Clinical Work</a></li>
            <li  onmouseover="changePreview('assessmentandresearch','0');" onmouseout="changePreview('blank','0');"><a href='?dp=14'>Assessment and Research</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='top'><a href='javascript:void();' class='top_link'>Locations</a>
        <ul class='sub'>
            <li  onmouseover="changePreview('haiti','0');" onmouseout="changePreview('blank','0');"><a href='?dp=12'>Haiti</a></li>
            <li  onmouseover="changePreview('jordan','0');" onmouseout="changePreview('blank','0');"><a href='?dp=16'>Jordan</a></li>
            <li  onmouseover="changePreview('unitedstates','0');" onmouseout="changePreview('blank','0');"><a href='?dp=15'>United States</a></li>
            <li  onmouseover="changePreview('jamaica','0');" onmouseout="changePreview('blank','0');"><a href='?dp=17'>Jamaica</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='top'><a href='javascript:void();' class='top_link'>Get Involved</a>
        <ul class='sub'>
            <li  onmouseover="changePreview('scheduleatraining','0');" onmouseout="changePreview('blank','0');"><a href='?dp=18'>Schedule A Training</a></li>
            <li  onmouseover="changePreview('requestservices','0');" onmouseout="changePreview('blank','0');"><a href='?dp=19'>Request Services</a></li>
            <li  onmouseover="changePreview('donatetodisasterrelief','0');" onmouseout="changePreview('blank','0');"><a href='?dp=20'>Donate To Disaster Relief</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='top'><a href='javascript:void();' class='top_link'>Contact</a>
        <ul class='sub'>
            <li  onmouseover="changePreview('contactus','0');" onmouseout="changePreview('blank','0');"><a href='?p=contact'>Contact Us</a></li>
            <li  onmouseover="changePreview('reportanerror','0');" onmouseout="changePreview('blank','0');"><a href='?p=webmaster'>Report An Error</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='top'><a href='BLOG URL HERE' class='top_link'>Blog</a></li>                  
</ul>
</div>
```

Why do the drop-down menus not trigger on :hover?  Thanks.

Comment: You need to put your img width and height declarations inside quotation marks.

Comment: I've never had to do that before.  Is that just a formatting preference?

Comment: I believe it is required for valid markup. Also, `<div>` is not a valid child of `<ul>`. Oh, and neither is `<img>`.

Comment: If I cannot have a `<div>` in my `<ul>` then how do you suppose I separate the preview image from the navigation `<li>` elements?  As far as I can tell, that's the only way.  But regardless of all that, I want to find what is causing the actual problem here.

Comment: Well I'm not sure about putting them in quotation marks (but I know you *should* do it), but I **do** know you need to add a space between the height px value and the closing `/>` tag for your image.

Comment: Quotes and spacing have been corrected on the live site.  The problem at hand still remains.

Comment: Try using `::hover` instead of the single colon.

Comment: It seems that everywhere I try that, it stops working on all browsers.

Comment: @TylerH While it's always a good idea to put attribute values in quotes, it's not necessary in HTML (and not the cause of any problem), only in XHTML. Then again, the closing slash in the start tag does look like the OP is aiming for polyglot compatibility, so it might be a good idea after all. The space before the closing slash is also a good idea (for display in very old browsers), but not vital.

Comment: @BitFracture Valid markup would be good though. Errors are bad, because different browsers respond differently to errors! So don't put a `div` in an `ul`. If you want some list items and an image in a block, make the outer block a `div` and put the `ul` inside it, next to the `img`.

Comment: @davidxd333 Why are you suggesting that? What good would introducing more errors do? Don't you think the OP has enough errors in their source?

Comment: Yea, don't listen to a person just asking you to attempt another method. You can't just say not to listen to a person, I'm not wrong.

Comment: @MrLister The thing is, the menus used to work fine on all browsers and I've done something to the css that messed it up.  I have backup versions I am going to start going through them to try to solve this.  I will look into a way to properly place the elements within the navigation as soon as I resolve why they don't appear on :hover anymore.

Comment: @davidxd333 I do appreciate your method and I did attempt it.  Unfortunately that didn't work, regardless of which :hover's I replaced.

Comment: @davidxd333 Sorry, but your suggestion was wrong. `:hover` is correct, `::hover` is an error. It's a pseudo-class, not a pseudo-element! See an explanation of the differences [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-classes).

Comment: @MrLister I have tried this code without the `div` and `img` tags and it is still not working.  I've also tried z-index and a blank image background instead of `background-color: transparent;`.  Regardless of correct or incorrect formatting, do you or anyone else have any other ideas of what might be causing `:hover` to be ignored?  It is very important for more people than myself that I get this solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many may know, Internet Explorer is very picky about some syntax.  One thing it is picky about is the `<!DOCTYPE>` tag.  As it turns out, I had used a `<div>` element before the doctype declaration in order to hide any unwanted output due to MySQL errors.  My replacement solution is to clear output buffering via PHP instead of the cheap work-around of a hidden `<div>`.

I use output buffering to allow me to redirect my PHP pages even after rendering content on the page.  Once output buffering is set up, using `ob_clean();` at any time will tell PHP to dump everything in the output buffer, thus preventing any errors or data before that point from being sent to the browser once the page is done rendering.